# JPlayer and wav file

Tags: javascript, xhtml, wav, jplayer

There is an issue with jPlayer and playing wav files. I tried to play a wav file but some of my buttons are not working as what they should like, my 'stop' button only pauses, then another is that I can't use my 'seekbar'.

Do you an idea on how to fix this thing?

Comment: Not familiar with jplayer, but I can imaging that this question could do with some more details. What is "properly"? What happens when you apply the CSS; what do you _want_ to happen? Show some examples.

Comment: I updated the question since I found out that there is nothing wrong with jplayer when playing other types like mp3, it's with the wav file that causes the issue.